# How can I render realistic in A-Frame

Tags: javascript, 3d, render, aframe

I import model to a-frame with obj and mtl like this :

```
<a-obj-model src="models/ladybug.obj" mtl="models/ladybug.mtl" 
scale="0.03 0.03 0.03"></a-obj-model>
```

How Can I render this model in a-frame with realistic quality like vray in c4d or similar render engines

Comment: i think it depends on the model, not on the engine. Three.js (a-frame's, base) is pretty powerful. Your 'realistic quality' may lay in materials ( textures, material/roughness/metalness/refraction/ambient occlusion mapping)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A-Frame is meant for building VR experiences, meaning the renderer (three.js-based) must run at >=90FPS. The three.js WebGL renderer can give very good results (examples: https://threejs.org/), but is not the same as slower non-realtime renderers like C4D provides. Those renderers are not able to run fast enough for VR, and are not supported by A-Frame.

If you want to do that type of high-quality rendering on the web, you will probably want to use [three.js](https://threejs.org/) directly, instead of A-Frame, along with one of the third-party pathtracing renderers. See thread here: https://twitter.com/alteredq/status/932729847301967873.

It's possible that someone could create pathtracing extensions for A-Frame using those renderers, but that's probably a significant amount of work.

If you are asking how you can get the highest-quality rendering possible within the limits of VR and A-Frame support, then learning about using modeling tools and PBR materials is a good place to start, but that's too broad a question for Stack Overflow.